# yii project show blank page in ubuntu?

Tags: php, ubuntu, yii

I'm new to linux(ubuntu v 12.04),I installed yii framework,then I created a new project using yiic command,when I run the project I just give a blank page with no error.what is the reason?can any body help me?

Comment: Have you installed apache and everything else you need?

Comment: yes,I can run other projects,but just yii projects show me a white page.

Comment: You have to tell us what's the URL you use to access your project and where its files is found on your files system path.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

On your `/index.php` file, add `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the beginning. Save the file and reload your home page.

That should come up with an error which will allow you to see where the problem is.

Comment: Great!
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Its because your php settings are to not show error messages, instead it log them to file. You can see your errors if u go to /var/log/apache2/ and open file error.log. If you wish to change this settings and get your errors printed on screen (what is useful for developer machine) you can update you php.ini. You can find it on this path /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini. Find line in file 'display_errors' and change it to be display_errors = On. Than also find line 'error_reporting' and change it to be error_reporting = E_ALL. I hope this will help.